# How to Override Magento Template File

Tags: php, magento

I want to override

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\type\select.phtml
```

and replace it with my custom module. I was unable to replace the file. I placed my custom file at this location and I created a `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\mymodule.xml` file:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <Mycompany_Mymodule>
                <file>Mycompany_Mymodule.xml</file>
            </Mycompany_Mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

But this did not replace the file. Any ideas on what I should try?

Comment: That is someone you want to add to your question (in the future when you post it) so that others can eliminate possible solutions :)

Comment: I created mymodule.xml file and place it in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout and also place modified file in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\Mycompany_Mymodule\product\edit\options\type.

In mymodule.xml file write the following lines.

<adminhtml>
 <layout>
  <updates>
   <Mycompany_Mymodule>
    <file>Mycompany_Mymodule.xml</file>
   </Mycompany_Mymodule>
  </updates>
 </layout>
</adminhtml>
and enabled it from mymodule config.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options I can think of:

Copy over the core template to: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/**my_namespace**/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml

A. Rewrite the block type: adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select, overload the constructor, call setTemplate with your template's path.

OR

B. Hook into core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before and for that block class call setTemplate with your template's path.

Another option, which I'm not sure is recommended, it's possible to add set the theme for the admin via a module's config.xml:

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                 <default>mytheme</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Then you would drop in your modified template into: app/design/adminhtml/default/**mytheme**/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml.

A note about this approach is that I recall on some versions of magento a community module (the find) which was bundled with magento (not sure if it was just with the enterprise edition) implemented this approach.

Comment: I tried set the theme via module's config.xml file and its really work fine but it is recommended to use it?? because whenever magento version updates then in this case may be its not working.

Comment: Thanks @beep logic you save my impotent time. Thanks a lot.